# How to tell auto tools to use different implementations in different folders

Tags: c, autotools, automake

I have a project that currently uses a communication library for communication. The library is not generic; it only runs on some machines. I want to port my project to be able to use a other libraries for communication. To do that, I defined a abstract layer that has different implementations. These implementations are consists of several files, so I want to group them into different folders.

For example, I might have a implementation that uses tcp, and another uses some system native library for communication. I have a folder `tcp` and a folder `native` in my `src` folder. I want the autotools to use one implementation that is selected at configure time with `--with-comm=XXX`.

How do I structure the Makefile.am to achieve this? I've read this: [Different implementations in different files in autotools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057098/different-implementations-in-different-files-in-autotools), 
but that one uses only different files for different implementations, but I want to use folders.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`AC_ARG_WITH`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#External-Software) macro in `configure.ac`, but it's more appropriate to use [`AC_ARG_ENABLE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Package-Options) for internal, compile-time features. e.g., in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([comm], [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-comm[[=tcp]]],
                  [specify a communications layer (default=tcp)])],
              , [enable_comm=yes])

enable_comm=`echo $enable_comm` # strip whitespace.

if test "x$enable_comm" = "xyes" || "x$enable_comm" = "xtcp" ; then
  enable_tcp="yes"
elif test "x$enable_comm" = "xnative" ; then
  enable_native="yes"
elif test "x$enable_comm" = "xno" ; then
  ; # ... error message? default to a dummy layer implementation?
else
  AC_MSG_ERROR([unknown option: '$enable_comm' for --enable-comm])
fi

AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_COMM_TCP], [test "x$enable_tcp" = "xyes"])
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_COMM_NATIVE], [test "x$enable_native" = "xyes"])
...
AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/tcp/Makefile src/native/Makefile])
...
AC_OUTPUT
```

You can, of course, put whatever you like in the help string, and set defaults differently.

In `src/Makefile.am`:

```
if ENABLE_COMM_TCP
COMM_DIR = tcp
endif

if ENABLE_COMM_NATIVE
COMM_DIR = native
endif

SUBDIRS = . $(COMM_DIR) # or '$(COMM_DIR) .' for depth-first order.
```

There are limitations because of the way automake works. It would be nice to be able to set `COMM_DIR` through a condition variable, but AFAIK this doesn't work. Furthermore, this approach automatically includes both `tcp` and `native` folders in the distribution if you use `make dist`. There's no need to put either in the [`EXTRA_DIST`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Subdirectories-with-AC_005fSUBST) list, though it might be a better approach if the number of optional 'layers' becomes unwieldy.

---

If I understand your comments correctly, then the simple way would be to include the `src` files in the subdirectory build, so `src/tcp/Makefile.am` would use:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libcomm.la
libcomm_la_SOURCES = driver.h driver.c ../comm.h ../wrapper.c ...
```

I can't remember offhand if `comm.h` needs to be specified as `$(srcdir)/../comm.h` for out-of-tree builds to work correctly. `src/Makefile.am` may or may not need to add `comm.h`, `wrapper.c`, etc., to its `EXTRA_DIST` variable. While this should work, it's not the 'right' way to go about things...

---

The library proper should be built in `src`, and that means using convenience libraries in either `tcp` or `native`, and letting `libtool` worry about the rest. e.g., `src/Makefile`:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libcomm.la
libcomm_include_HEADERS = comm.h
libcomm_la_SOURCES = comm.h wrapper.c utils.c ...
libcomm_la_LIBADD = ./$(COMM_DIR)/libcomm_layer.la
```

It will also be necessary to order: `SUBDIRS = $(COMM_DIR) .`

In `src/tcp/Makefile.am`

```
AM_CPPFLAGS += -I$(srcdir)/.. # look for core headers in src

noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libcomm_layer.la # not for installation.
libcomm_layer_la_SOURCES = driver.h driver.c ...
# libcomm_layer_la_LDFLAGS = -static # optional... an archive is preferable.
```

This is a more future-proof approach as your 'core' and 'layer' libraries become more complex - and they will:)

Comment: Thanks Brett! It's very helpful! One more question: I have some common files in `src` folder. How do I write `src/Makefile.am` to include these common src files as well? Should I directly set myproject_a_SOURCES=[ common files ], then have `src/tcp/Makefile.am` append to myproject_a_SOURCES+=[ tcp impl src files ]?

Comment: @Chaoran - do you mean `src` files you want to be used in the build of, say, `tcp`, or you want to compile files in `src` and add the `tcp` objects to it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand the difference between the two cases. both source files in `tcp` and `native` define the same set of functions of an interface (comm.h). I suppose comm.h should be in the `src` folder, right? `src` also includes some utility functions in utils.c which is used by both `tcp` and `native` implementations.

Comment: Good answer, but why don't you just specify enable_comm=tcp in the `ACTION-IF-NOT-GIVEN` part of the `AC_ARG_ENABLE`?

Comment: @JackKelly - I only added a 'default' as an afterthought. There might still be syntax errors lurking in the (untested) examples too.